# How to check if a value of a field exists in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I encountered a problem when editing a record. My issue is, when I edit a record, I have to check a field called `serial_number`. If it exists in my database (table contracts) the program will show the message to announce users that this value was existed, and if not then save to database.

Now I am confused of how to check that the `serial_number`'s value is existed or not.

I used  `Contract.exists?(params[:serial_nuber])` to check, but it returns false while `serial_number` value existed in `contracts` table before.

Can someone suggest how I solve this problem?

Comment: How do you get your contracts from the database, is it RubyOnRails (ActiveRecord::Base) ?

Comment: Sounds like you just want to validate uniqueness of the serial_number.  The message part then takes care of itself.

Comment: paste your code so that we will understand what is your exact problem

Comment: The validations suggested in answers are correct. Just be aware that business logic (such as uniqueness checking) should be handled in your models, not in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `Contract.exists?(params[:serial_number])` which is wrong it should be `Contract.exists?(serial_number: params[:serial_number])`
it will return true if the `serial_number` already exists in database.

OR

You can add validation in **contact.rb** file.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :serial_number, message: "Serial Number already exists."
```

Comment: Keeping validation logic in controller is not the best practice. I suggest the other option ie 'validates_uniqueness_of' would be best in this case

Comment: @ravi1991 thank you for your suggestion, but can you explain more detail about why it is not a good habit to put validation in controller?

Comment: Hi, if you check validations in controller action (say edit) now if any of your other code is updating the serial_number from any of other point.(ie say at one place you replace the serial_number with new one) then in that case that validation won't be checked.
And if you keep validation in model as I recommended above rails will take care to check validation each time when you are saving the object.

Answer (score 2):

```
validate :serial_number, uniqueness: true
```

Add this line to contact.rb. This will check if existed serial number should not be added with other contract.